# OnEditFinished listener or something equivalent?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I'm looking for a sort of event listener that triggers after a transform has finished.
So far i found this:

```
def scene_update(context):
    if bpy.data.objects.is_updated:
        print("One or more objects were updated!")
        for ob in bpy.data.objects:
            if ob.is_updated:
                print("=>", ob.name)
bpy.app.handlers.scene_update_post.append(scene_update)
```

I need to add something so that the print only happens after the translation of a vertex is completed (not while i'm still dragging the vertices around).
Any idea what ?

Comment: his could help : http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/44971/5113

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a mix of the answers here [Find out if Mesh Operator (bpy.ops.mesh...) was cancelled or not via python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36960/find-out-if-mesh-operator-bpy-ops-mesh-was-cancelled-or-not-via-python/36968#36968) and [How to get the active vertex within a Handler?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40233/how-to-get-the-active-vertex-within-a-handler/40264#40264)

Looks for bpy.ops.transform.translate as the active operator and if used prints out the selected verts and amount transformed.

```
import bpy, bmesh
from bpy.app.handlers import persistent
from mathutils import Vector

def check_operators(bm):
    op = bpy.context.active_operator
    if op:
        if op.bl_idname == 'TRANSFORM_OT_translate':  #bpy.ops.transform.translate.idname()
            #print("bpy.ops.transform.translate(%s)" % " ,".join(["%s=%s" % (k, str(v)) for k, v in op.properties.items()]))
            print(op.name)
            v = Vector(op.properties["value"])
            if v.length:
                print("value", str(v))
                print("verts", [v for v in bm.verts if v.select])
            else:
                print("operator canceled")

dic = {}
@persistent
def edit_object_change_handler(scene):

    obj = scene.objects.active
    if obj is None:
        return None

    if obj.mode == 'EDIT' and obj.type == 'MESH':
        bm = dic.setdefault(obj.name, bmesh.from_edit_mesh(obj.data))
        check_operators(bm)
        return None

    dic.clear()
    return None

def register():
    bpy.app.handlers.scene_update_post.clear() # for testing
    bpy.app.handlers.scene_update_post.append(edit_object_change_handler)

register()
```