# Restrict movement of objects or verts during G S R with python

Tags: python, 3d-view, add-on, transforms

I want to fool around with the selected objects/verts while doing GSR, mostly translate. A bit like a constraint. Is there a tutorial out there on doing that?

Main problem: What would be the right way to make sure a script is only active while 
a: moving objects and/or
b: moving verts?

I guess it would be possible to append the function to bpy.app.handlers.scene_update_pre
It doesn't feel right to have the script check whether it's going to be used all the time.

Comment: Related http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/48767/15543  Edit / Object mode will tell you if you are moving obs or verts.

Comment: That helps a bit but the main uncertainty remains. Does the scripthave to run all the time? I just found out that the scene gets updated even without me doing anything.

Comment: I would suggest making a modal operator to replace the standard `bpy.ops.transform.translate`, start with the [modal_view3d template](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/release/scripts/templates_py/operator_modal_view3d.py) and as suggested use mode to decide if you want to change the object location or the selected vertices location.